# D3.js graph not updated correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a beginner with D3.js. To update my graph, I've read [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218)

You can see an example of my graph on this [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/7qk16oj5/)

Why the arcs are not updated correctly ?

EDIT :
You can see on the browser console the logs : when I click on the update button, the id of the updated element is not the new element added but the id of an element that already exist in the old json.

Comment: do you want to place the big circle properly?

Comment: No ... It's just a quick example. When you click on the 'update' button you can see that the order from the 'jsonDataUpdated' is not keep. I don't understand why.